# MooTools DatePicker library: 'value' is empty if the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mootools

I'm trying to use DatePicker library for Date fields but when the form is submitted, the 'value' of the input field is empty.
I copied the code from here: http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker

```
<script>           
        window.addEvent('load', function() {
        new DatePicker('.demo_vista', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_vista' });
        new DatePicker('.demo_dashboard', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_dashboard' });
        new DatePicker('.demo_jqui', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_jqui', positionOffset: { x: 0, y: 5 } });
        new DatePicker('.demo', { positionOffset: { x: 0, y: 5 }});

         });
</script>
    <li>*DATE : <input name='date' type='text' value='' class='date demo_vista'  /></li>
```

This is my website: http://iconceptsolutions.com.my/projects/grandevest/online-product-registration/

Answer (score 2):

The point with this library is that the field you write into your HTML document is not the same that is shown by the browser.

When you build the `DatePicker` object, it takes the `input fields` which match its first parameter, and for each of them it builds another `input field` wich actually gets the dates selected by the user and is shown by the browser.

So, to get the value you are looking for, you must get a reference to the original `input field`, and with it call the MooTools function `getNext()`, so that you can retrieve the wanted value:

So, for this HTML:

```
<input name='date' type='text' value='' class='date demo' id='dateField' />
```

you can get the wanted value with this code:

```
$('dateField').getNext().get('value')
```

Wich can be called, for example, when the user clicks the submit button. If you need the value at a PHP script which will process the form, then with the MooTools line above you could set the value of the original `input field`, and then send it to the PHP.

---

**UPDATE**

I've set up [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRYQw/) for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I wonder if your

`value=''`

in

`<li>*DATE : <input name='date' type='text' value='' class='date demo_vista'  /></li>`

is overwriting the calendar?

What happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input id="datepicker" name='date' type='text'/>
```

The javascript function new datepicker is creating 'datepicker' as a DOM object with the ID datepicker.  You need the ID in the tag to specifiy this.  You don't need the value in there at all, you can set a default value in the datepicker script itself in the header.  That is also where you pick the theme, not in your HTML tags.

Comment: ok now i can get the data but the date format is now really different i choose this date 03-11-2011 but in email the format change to this DATE : 1320553106...how to change this format?

Comment: Are you using PHP?  That looks like a unix timestamp format possibly.  If you're using PHP you'd want something like date("m-d-y", $date). 

Edit: Oh I see, you are using PHP.  Try what I just said, or maybe it has to be date("m-d-y", strtotime($date)).  One of those should convert that format back to something normal.  Look up the date function in the PHP manual.